# Adjust y axis limits in dual y axis ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, transform, yaxis

I am trying to generate a figure overlaying a geom_line over a geom_bar where the x axes are different scales (weekly vs daily). I am able to plot what I want, but cannot adjust the Temp y axis to have limits 24-30 without interfering with the 1 to 1 transformation of the secondary axis. Below are 2 very small subsets of the dataframes and an example plot. I want the Degree Heating Weeks axis to remain the same but adjust the Temp axis to 24-30.

```
    a <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18116, 18117, 18118, 18119, 18120, 18121, 18122, 
    18123, 18124, 18125, 18126, 18127, 18128, 18129, 18130, 18131, 18132, 18133, 18134, 18135, 
    18136), class = "Date"), Temp2019 = c(29.0416666666667, 29.1375, 29.4125, 29.3833333333333, 
    29.575, 29.5541666666667, 29.2458333333333, 29.2416666666667, 29.0666666666667, 
    29.0541666666667, 28.9833333333333, 29.0625, 28.9958333333333, 29.1, 28.9625, 
    29.0041666666667, 29.0791666666667, 28.9, 28.675, 28.4916666666667, 28.5625), Max2019 = 
    c(29.3, 29.5, 29.6, 29.6, 29.8, 29.9, 29.6, 29.6, 29.3, 29.3, 29.3, 29.4, 29.4, 29.4, 29.2, 
    29.3, 29.6, 29.2, 29, 28.7, 28.9), Min2019 = c(28.3, 28.5, 29, 29, 29.1, 29.1, 28.8, 28.8, 
    28.8, 28.8, 28.6, 28.6, 28.7, 28.7, 28.6, 28.6, 28.4, 28.4, 28.2, 28.1, 28.1)), row.names = 
    100:120, class = "data.frame")

    b <- structure(list(Week = c("32", "33", "34"), DHW = c(3.05952380952381, 3.20833333333333, 
    3.26785714285714), Date = structure(c(18120, 18127, 18134), class = "Date")), row.names = 
    15:17, class = "data.frame")

    ggplot() + 
        geom_ribbon(a, mapping = aes(x = Date, ymin = Min2019, ymax = Max2019), alpha = 0.2, linetype = "blank", color = "black", fill = "black") + 
        geom_line(a, mapping = aes(Date, Temp2019), color = "black") + 
        geom_bar(b, mapping = aes(Date, DHW*6, fill = DHW), stat = "identity") +
        scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./6, name = "Degree Heating Weeks")) +
        scale_fill_gradient(high = "#DD6666", low = "#F8E1E1") + 
        scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 week") + 
        labs(y = "Temp (°C)")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the challenge here is that `geom_bar/geom_col` has a baseline of zero, so I don't know of a way to use that geom where your y-axis does not include 0 in it's range. So you could use `geom_tile` in its place, specifying the center y point and the height.

Here's the original for reference:
[image]

As a first step, we can test the use of `geom_tile` where the two axes use the same vertical distance for 1 unit. To do so, we shift the bar data up by 24 (so its baseline is 24), and shift the labeling down 24 (so that 24 on the primary axis appears as 0 on the secondary one). For `geom_tile`, we define y as `DHW/2 + 24` since we want the middle height of the tile.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_tile(data = b, aes(Date, DHW/2 + 24, width = 7*0.9, height = DHW, fill = DHW)) +
  geom_ribbon(data = a, aes(x = Date, ymin = Min2019, ymax = Max2019), 
              alpha = 0.2, linetype = "blank", color = "black", fill = "black") + 
  geom_line(data = a, aes(Date, Temp2019), color = "black") + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.-24, name = "Degree Heating Weeks")) +
  scale_fill_gradient(high = "#DD6666", low = "#F8E1E1") + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 week") + labs(y = "Temp (°C)")
```

[image]

If we want to stretch the bars to take up more space, say 1.5 dec C per Degree Heating Week, we add that scale to both the data and the scale transformation, in opposite directions.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_tile(data = b, aes(Date, DHW/2*1.5 + 24, width = 7*0.9, height = DHW*1.5, fill = DHW)) +
  geom_ribbon(data = a, aes(x = Date, ymin = Min2019, ymax = Max2019), 
              alpha = 0.2, linetype = "blank", color = "black", fill = "black") + 
  geom_line(data = a, aes(Date, Temp2019), color = "black") + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~(.-24)/1.5, name = "Degree Heating Weeks")) +
  scale_fill_gradient(high = "#DD6666", low = "#F8E1E1") + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 week") + labs(y = "Temp (°C)")
```

[image]

Season to taste.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I've never used geom_tile before. this does the trick with a little modifying.